# Finding DB info based on Datasource

Tags: coldfusion, datasource, coldfusion-9

I am looking to get the DB server and database info from the Datasource name.

I have tried using `<cfdbinfo>` but it doesn't seem to have any of that information

```
<cfdbinfo
    type="dbnames"
    datasource="#dsn#"
    name="dbdata">

<cfoutput>
The #dsn# data source has the following databases:<br />
</cfoutput>
<cfdump var="#dbdata#">
```

I am looking to get the info highlighted in yellow[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create an object of the admin API, login and then create an object of the datasource API as follows:

```
<cfset admin_api = createObject('component', 'cfide.adminapi.administrator')>
<cfset admin_api.login('cf_admin_password_here')>
<cfset admin_api_dsn = createObject('component', 'cfide.adminapi.datasource')>
```

Then from there you can use the methods exposed by the datasource API to retrieve the information you require.

Another option would be to read in the file `neo-datasource.xml` from the `{cf_root}/lib/ directory`, parse that using xmlparse and then read the data from there.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another method my co-worker came up with several years ago.

```
<cfobject type="JAVA" action="Create" name="factory"
class="coldfusion.server.ServiceFactory">
<cfscript>
sqlexecutive = factory.getDataSourceService();
//get data sources 
ds=sqlexecutive.getDatasources();
</cfsript>
```

Not sure if it's better or worse than Andrew's methods, but it's nice to have options.

Comment: I like that it does not require the admin password